# Linkedlist (collections) in java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am new to collections and I am trying to figure out why there are so many similar methods in LinkedList class in Java.

for ex.

1. element() returns head of the list without deleting but so does peek and peekFirst
2. addLast, offer, offerLast are also similar
3. remove and removeFirst

Do these different functions have any specific applications?

Thanks for any advice and feel free to correct me

Comment: _Some functions have different return types_. So they are **not** the same. Some also throw exceptions and others return `null`. Consult the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedList` is a `List`, but it is also a `Deque` which is also a `Queue`.

These 3 interfaces offer variations in functionalities. For example, `element` and `peek` are defined in `Queue`, but one returns a special value while the other throws an exception if there is no value to return. `peekFirst` is specific to `Deque`, because a `Deque` can be `peeked` from both ends.

The same principle applies to other methods. (add vs offer is a matter of return vs exception, offerFirst is a Deque specific method...).

I should agree, though, that the `Deque` interface is a bit weird. It basically triplicates everything a `Queue` does, by forcing the implementation to implement the `Queue` version of the method, plus both `Deque` version (one for each end). It is even explicated in the doc:

> The methods inherited from the Queue interface are precisely equivalent to Deque methods